# Como indentar o código no Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Como faço para indentar meu código XML e JAVA no Android Studio?
Também gostaria de saber como aumentar a fonte do código.

Comment: Você tentou ir nesta sequência do menu? `Settings>Editor>Colors&Fonts>Font` Escolheu a fonte/tamanho desejado e mandou salvar a nova configuração?

Comment: sim, mas está bloqueado!

Answer (score 9):

Para identar o código tem o atalho: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, (ou se preferir selecione o código que você quer identar antes).

Para aumentar a fonte:

File ➝ Settings ➝ Editor ➝ Colors&Fonts ➝ Font. Vá em *Save As...* coloca um nome e da ok, ai vai desbloquear as opções, inclusive a *Size* onde vai poder aumentar a fonte. (só desbloqueia se salvar um novo scheme antes).

Comment: Gente, no Ubuntu o Crtl + Alt + L é o comando para bloquear a seção do usuário. Para quem passar por isso, tem alternativa aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580171/code-formatting-shortcut-in-android-studio

Comment: isso, no windows não tem esse atalho.

Answer (score 2):

Windows: Ctrl + Alt + L

Linux: Ctrl + Shift + Alt + L

macOS: Option + Command + L